Debugger never attaches when debugging a local Python 3.11 Azure Function App (Queue Triggered)
I have a Python 3.11 Function App that runs locally. I'm developing on Windows 11, and VS Code, fwiw.
I have all of the Azure extensions; I have the Azure Tools extension pack, which includes the Functions extension, installed/enabled. It works great for other types of Function Apps and App Services we use.
func host start starts the application as expected. I am connected to a remote queue storage account -- I can drop messages onto the queue and see it get picked up by my locally-running app.
I'd love to be able to debug and step through the code when it processes a message. However, I have a breakpoint set right where I know code is getting executed, as well as other lines, and I never see them get hit. I know the debugger is not attached, because I don't see the debugger controls
So, I have the following launch.json:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach to Python Functions",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "attach",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "connect": {
                "host": "localhost",
                "port": 7071
            },
            "preLaunchTask": "func: host start",
            "env": {
                "PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION": "1"
            }
        }
    ]
}

tasks.json:
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "func",
            "label": "func: host start",
            "command": "host start --port 7071 --enable-debugging",
            "problemMatcher": "$func-python-watch",
            "isBackground": true,
            "dependsOn": "pip install (functions)"
        },
        {
            "label": "pip install (functions)",
            "type": "shell",
            "osx": {
                "command": "${config:azureFunctions.pythonVenv}/bin/python -m pip install -r requirements.txt"
            },
            "windows": {
                "command": "${config:azureFunctions.pythonVenv}\\Scripts\\python -m pip install -r requirements.txt"
            },
            "linux": {
                "command": "${config:azureFunctions.pythonVenv}/bin/python -m pip install -r requirements.txt"
            },
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}

My local.settings.json holds nothing exciting:
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
  }
}

Here's a screenshot showing the app is running fine:

So what gives? Why, when pushing F5, the Function App spins up fine, but the debugger does not attach?

UPDATE:
Here are my debugpy and Azure Core Function Tools versions

Did you upgrade Function Core Tools?

See screenshot. Azure Function Core Tools is version 4.0.6610 -- the most recent version

To debug locally and hitting it with a break point, you have to use Start Debugging in Run as below:

Now add a break point and it will hit now, when you click on Start Debugging:

Even when I press F5 it is working with :
launch.json:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach to Python Functions",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "attach",
            "connect": {
                "host": "localhost",
                "port": 9091
            },
            "preLaunchTask": "func: host start"
        }
    ]
}

tasks.json:
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "func",
            "label": "func: host start",
            "command": "host start",
            "problemMatcher": "$func-python-watch",
            "isBackground": true,
            "dependsOn": "pip install (functions)"
        },
        {
            "label": "pip install (functions)",
            "type": "shell",
            "osx": {
                "command": "${config:azureFunctions.pythonVenv}/bin/python -m pip install -r requirements.txt"
            },
            "windows": {
                "command": "${config:azureFunctions.pythonVenv}\\Scripts\\python -m pip install -r requirements.txt"
            },
            "linux": {
                "command": "${config:azureFunctions.pythonVenv}/bin/python -m pip install -r requirements.txt"
            },
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}

Try installing the debugpy:
Firstly check if debugpy:
pip show debugpy


If not there install it:
pip install debugpy
pip show debugpy


Upgrade Azure Function Core Tools.
Alternatively, you can also check here:

For further information refer SO-Thread1 and SO-Thread2 and Microsoft-Document.

you're demonstrating an HTTP trigger app, which works fine for me to both run and debug. My Function is a queue-trigger function. Also, you mentioned I should upgrade Azure Function Core Tools. From my screenshot, you can see I'm on v4.0.6610, the latest version. One peculiar thing I noticed is that your port is 9091 in the debug configurations in launch.json. However, when I start the Function App, there is nothing listening on port 9091; the Function App is listening on port 7071

Queue Trigger also worked for me, it does not depend it is queue or http trigger.

What about the port I mentioned? None of your suggestions helped, unfortunately.

You're also using Python 3.10. My post mentions I'm using 3.11

9091 is the debugger port
